# Write/read class objects to/from file, D-Lang

Tags: oop, class, io, d

I'm trying to write/read a class object from/to a file.
I'm new to D and I just want to play a little bit around with it.

Is there a Class/Function to write/read an object to/from a file?
I'm looking for something similar to the `ObjectOutputStream` сlass in Java.

Or do I have to serialize (concatenate) the object's variables as strings in the file?

I have a `Movie` class and a `MovieManager` class, which contains a dynamic movie-array.

A `Movie` object contains just a few strings and integer values.

Comment: Forum thread about object serialization: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/hejwzazwkfkmuxjoledo@forum.dlang.org

Comment: Thank you!
That's exactly what I was looking for. 
Shame on me, that I don't found it myself..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending answer, provided in comment, it is worth explicitly stating, that D does not provide "one true way" of reading/writing objects to/from files, as there can't be a single optimal one. Different considerations about speed, resulting file format, handling references and similar corner cases may results in different serialization strategies.

That being said, most likely proper serialization library is needed, and, by lucky chance, one of most mature D solutions ("Orange" by Jacob Carlborg  https://github.com/jacob-carlborg/orange) is being reviewed right now as a candidate for inclusion into standard library as a `std.serialization`: [newsgroup thread](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/kinpnv%24ven%241@digitalmars.com). It may be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

The library [Unmanaged](https://github.com/BBasile/Unmanaged) provides a serialization system. You also have [Orange](https://github.com/jacob-carlborg/orange)
 which is less restrictive, as Unmanaged serialization only works if the object to serialize is an ancestor of one of the framework base class.But...Unmanaged works on the "accessor" principle. The data serialized are get via a method and the data deserialized are set via a method, which allows to update some stuffs when the deserializer recall for example...